# Still disk i/o is faster than network i/o?

Tags: io

At the past, generally disk i/o is faster than network i/o.
But at [Are networks now faster than disks?](https://serverfault.com/questions/238417/are-networks-now-faster-than-disks), network i/o seems faster than disk i/o.

Sure 11 years have passed since the link, technology has advanced, and network i/o was once faster than disk i/o.

Using cloud storage is general for most company, it seems better to know diffrence of i/o speed and understand why it is happened.

Comment: Some simple understanding tells me: If you have a local disk, and you have the same kind of disk somewhere else. Then, the local disk will be faster.